# Tonsillitis and tonsillectomy confusion

Tags: immune-system, tonsil-tonsillectomy, tonsillitis

I have read the article [here](http://www.kevinmd.com/blog/2011/08/tonsils.html), and I am confused on why the tonsils have to be removed.

Are tonsils removed when they themselves incur frequent/prolonged infection? The source I stated above does not mention this. It simply states tonsillitis as inflammation of the tonsils and that the tonsils become inflamed and red when fighting an infection like a cold etc, in which case removing them would not make sense at all since all they are doing is fighting the infection.